# BASH script checking log files for current and previous month

Tags: bash, date, for-loop

I have been working on this on and off for the last two months, and despite how many times I look at it, I can't make it work.
This script checks daily log files for a user defined variable, so they don't have to look through every one manually. It worked great checking the current month, but if the user wants to check back 20 days, and today is the 12th of this month, I wanted to be able to then go back to the previous month (not look for the log file with a date of 20150399 and so on). I have checked the logic for my date/day computations, and they seem okay (if there is a better way to do that in BASH, I am open to suggestions). What happens when I try to debug is unexpected end of file. I am somewhat new to writing scripts that contain more than 20 or so lines, but I just can't come up with what I am missing.
I have tried various fixes, to no avail, but I think this is the last iteration.
Ideas?

```
#!/bin/bash
########################################################
# multi_log_chk.sh
# This script will take input from the user and report which
# CyberFusion MFT logs contain what the user is looking for.
# Hopefully this will save the user having to search through every
# stinking log file to find what they are looking for.
# 20150406 pxg007 started typing
# 20150413 pxg007 added && comparison for back out (line 28)
#                 added message for no entries found (line 32, 38, 48-52)
#                                 Added some further description (line 16)
# 20150424 pxg007 Added logic to calculate previous month and if necessary, year. (Lines 16-24, 60-78 )
#
########################################################

currDate=`date +%d%B%C%y`
currDay=`date +%d`
currMnth=`date +%m`
currYear=`date +%C%y`
 case $currMnth in                                                                                              #Let's establish number of days for previous month
        05 | 07 | 10 | 12 )  lastMnthD=30;;
        01 |02 | 04 | 06 | 09 | 08 | 11 )  lastMnthD=31;;
        03 ) lastMnthD=28;;                                                                             ##and screw leap year
esac
if [ $currMnth -eq 01 ]; then                                                                   ##accounting for January
        lastMnth=12
        else
        lastMnth=$((currMnth-1))
fi
if [ $lastMnth -eq 12 ]; then                                                           ## accounting for Dec of previous year
        lastMnthYr=$((currYear-1))
        else
        lastMnthYr=$currYear
fi


echo "This script will find entries for your query in whatever available MFT logs you request."
echo " "
echo "For instance - how many log files have transfer entries with \"DOG\" in them?"
echo " "
echo "I also will also give an estimate of how many transfers per log file contain your query, give or take a couple."
echo " "
echo "This search is case sensitive, so \"DOG\" is *** NOT *** the same as \"dog\""
echo " "
read -p "What text you are looking for? Punctuation is okay, but no spaces please. " looking          ### what we want to find
echo " "
echo "Today's date is: $currDate."
echo " "
read -p "How many days back do you want to search(up to 25)? " daysBack                 ### How far back we are going to look
        if [ "$daysBack" == 0 ]  && [ "$daysBack" >> 25 ]; then
        echo "I said up to 25 days. We ain't got more than that!"
         exit 1
        fi
echo " "
echo "I am going to search through the last $daysBack days of log files for:\"$looking\" "
echo " "
read -p "Does this look right? Press N to quit, or any other key to continue:  " affirm
        if [ "$affirm" = N ] && [ "$affirm" = n ]; then  ###Yes, anything other than "N" or "n" is a go
         echo "Quitter!"
         exit 1
           else
                nada=0                                          ### Used to test for finding anything
                backDate=$((currDay-daysBack))                  ### current month iterator (assuming query covers only current month)
                if (("$daysBack" => "$currDay")); then                  ## If there are more logs requested than days in the month...
                        lastMnthCnt=$((daysBack-currDay))                               ### how many days to check last month
                        lastMnthStrt=$((lastMnthD-lastMnthCnt))                 ## last month start and iterator
                        backDate=$(currDay-(daysBack-lastMnthCnt))              # Setting the iterator if we have to go back a month

                                while (("$lastMnthStrt" <= "$lastMnthD" )); do
                                foundIt=$(grep "$looking" /CyberFusion/log/Log.txt."$lastMnthYr$lastMnth$lastMnthStrt" | parsecflog | wc -l )
                                howMany=$((foundIt/40+1))                       ### Add one in case there are less than 40 lines in the record.
                                        if (("$foundIt" > 0))
                                        then
                                        nada=$((nada+1))
                                        echo "Log.txt.$lastMnthYr$lastMnth$lastMnthStrt contains $looking in approximately $howMany transfer records."
                                        lastMnthStrt=$((lastMnthStrt+1))
                                        echo " "
                                        else
                                        lastMnthStrt=$((lastMnthStrt+1))
                                        fi
                fi
                        backDate=$((currDay-daysBack))                  ### current month iterator (assuming query covers only current month)
                                while (("$backDate" <= "$currDay")); do
                                foundIt=$(grep "$looking" /CyberFusion/log/Log.txt."$backDate" | parsecflog | wc -l )
                                howMany=$((foundIt/40+1))                                               ### Add one in case there are less than 40 lines in the record.
                                        if (("$foundIt" > 0))
                                        then
                                        nada=$((nada+1))
                                        echo "Log.txt.$backDate contains $looking in approximately $howMany transfer records."
                                        backDate=$((backDate+1))
                                        echo " "
                                        else
                                        backDate=$((backDate+1))
                                        fi


                        if [ "$nada" \< 1 ]
                         then
                         echo " "
                        echo "I found no entries for $looking in any log file."
                        fi
```

Comment: did you ever try `date --date="-20 days" +"%d%B%C%y"`?

Comment: Is anything under that first `echo` line relevant to the question here? Because if it isn't you should remove it from the post.

Comment: I think it is. I'm pretty sure that the problem is somewhere in one of the if or while statements.  I pasted the whole thing just to give a better idea of what I was tyring to do with the whole mess.

Comment: Paste your script into [shellcheck.net](http://shellcheck.net).  There are several syntax errors.

Comment: Thank you rojomke! I knew that there had to be something somewhere that could assess my code better than BASH -x. This is just what I needed.

Answer (score 0):

You are missing the keyword 'done' on lines 81 and 96 and also a final 'fi' keyword on the last line.

Also as others suggested you can do

```
date -d "20 days ago" +"%d%B%C%y"
```

to easily get dates in the past